# What is this part of a kettledrum?

Tags: instruments, percussion, timpani

Here is a picture of a kettledrum (from [here](https://www.percussionsource.com/ludwig-standard-fiberglass-lts402fg-26-29-timpani-217754)). What is the name and function of the thing behind the pedal that is indicated in red?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the balance spring and its adjuster.

Timpani Owner's Manual AV3LU700 - Ludwig Drums

[image]